# SonarQube : Update existing analysis data

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, code-analysis

Scenario

- Compile code & run unit tests
- Execute sonar scan on code
- Once the scan completes, code coverage for unit tests + other analysis gets stored in sonar (lets call report1)

All good till now. Now once the application is deployed, we are run some integrations tests and manual tests are also performed.
All these tests will generate code coverage.

Now we have to merge unit test, integrations & manual tests code coverage and store it on sonar under same analysis report (basically update report1)

Any thoughts/suggestions for best practice or solution for same on sonar?

Comment: Maven plugin configuration can be created to do so

Comment: Any sample/reference will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple. Don't run the SonarQube scan until you've produced all the data you want to integrate into the report.

However, I would also point out that it's generally not worthwhile to generate code coverage for anything but unit tests.  If you can't reach it with a unit test, I don't see how you could reach it with any other test.

Comment: How can you release to QA team for testing if your unit tests don't cover x% of code coverage?
There will be always some scenarios we can't test using unit tests. For that ONLY manual testing can be done.

Comment: If you require a certain unit test code coverage percentage, then use a quality gate that specifies that, along with a build script that fails the build if the background task fails the quality gate.  Concerning the comment about unreachable code in unit tests, it's generally the opposite that is true, unit tests can almost always reach more code than manual testing.

Comment: That's not really a good solution. I for one find it very useful to first run Sonar before any testing to get immediate feedback on any potential bugs, security issues or code smells. I don't have to wait for the all the unit/integration tests (potentially very long) to finish to start cleaning up my code. Then when the testing is done I want Sonar to show me where I have bind-spots in my test coverage. This is a great separation for CI pipelines, so I think "just don't do it" isn't really a valid answer.